# Creating 'util' - stored procedure section, as with .net helper classes

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

A few minutes ago I was only searching for a simple syntax (SQL server) query that will copy a table Row .

This is usually done from time to time, when working on a ASP.net project, testing data with queries 
inside the *SQL SERVER management studio* . so one of the routine actions is copying a row, altering the required columns to be different from each other, then testing data with queries

So I've encountered  [- this stored procedure-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967665/how-can-i-copy-a-row-into-same-table-with-sql-server-2008) ,as answer by Dan Atkinson

but adding it to where all non testing purpose are stored lead me to think 
is it possible to store them in sorted order so I could Distinguish

'utils' or 'testingPurpose' ones from those used in projects

(default folder inside managment treeview is Programmabilty) could this be another folder too 
or this is not an option ?

if not , I thought of  `Utils.`  prefix like that (if no other way exist)

```
dbo.Utils.CopyTableRow
dbo.Utils.OtherRoutineActions ....
```

Or there's a designated way to achieve what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a first "Util" stored procedure i've made , found it's only solution 
prefexing it via Util_

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Utils_TableRowCopy](
@TableName VARCHAR(50) ,
@RowNumberToCopy INT
)



AS
BEGIN

declare @RowIdentity sysname =
(SELECT name FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE object_id = object_id(@TableName)
 )

DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(5000), @query VARCHAR(8000);
SET @query = '' ;

SELECT @columns =
    CASE
        WHEN @columns IS NULL THEN column_name
        ELSE @columns + ',' + column_name
    END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE (
    TABLE_NAME = LTRIM(RTRIM(@TableName))
    AND
    column_name <> LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowIdentity))
);

SET @query = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' (' + @columns + ') SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @RowIdentity + ' = ' + CAST(@RowNumberToCopy AS VARCHAR);

--SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
declare  @query2 VARCHAR(100) =  ' Select Top 1 * FROM '+ @TableName +' Order BY ' + @RowIdentity + ' desc' ;
EXEC (@query);
EXEC (@query2);
```

END